# How to fix "gcc: fatal error: cannot execute ?cc1plus?: execvp: No such file or directory"?

Tags: c++, docker, gcc

In a docker file I am trying to install `gcc` and all dependent libraries, but when I use the docker image to run some code inside I still get the error

```
gcc: fatal error: cannot execute ?cc1plus?: execvp: No such file or directory
```

I am already installing the following libraries:

```
gcc python3-dev python3-pip libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev
```

what else could I be missing?

In some other posts is mentioned to install `gcc-c++`, but when I add the package `gcc-c++` to the list of packages to be installed, I get an error

```
E: Unable to locate package gcc-c+
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gcc-c+'
```

Hint: I triple checked, the package name is in fact `gcc-c++` (with two plus signs!).

Any ideas?

Comment: The GCC C++ compiler frontend program is called `g++`.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to solve my problem!